# smart barcode not working in Android React Native

Tags: android, react-native, barcode-scanner

Hello friends i want to integrate smart barcode library in my react native project so i intgrate it 
https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-barcode#readme

but when i run my code i got error like                                                                 **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'boolean com.reactnativecomponent.barcode.view.ViewfinderView.drawLine' on a null object reference** in CaptureView.java any idea how can i solve these?

Answer (score 0):

It seems library is not well maintained. There is the similar issue posted by other user [NullPointerException in android](https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-barcode/issues/12) but there is no response from owner or other users. I think if there is anything that you can do is, debug the android code and change accordingly.

I will suggest instead of doing debugging for android and change code in node-modules it will take much time and not also a good solution.

You can use other library for barcode scanning

[react-native-barcodescanner](https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner)
[react-native-barcode-scanner-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-barcode-scanner-google)